# TYPO3 findDemanded return an empty array

Tags: arrays, typo3, typo3-8.x

i'm struggling with a tricky problem.
I'm creating a new extension for typo3, this extension need to retrive all the news matching the demand-array.

Actually my code looks like this:

```
    $demand = $this->objectManager->get(NewsDemand::class);
    $demand->setActionAndClass(__METHOD__, __CLASS__);
    $demand->setStoragePage(18);

    $res = $this->findDemanded($demand);
```

the main problem is that

```
$res->count()
```

this code retrieve correctly the number of news matching the array but if i try with

```
$res->getFirst()
```

this return nothing.

In theory the code **$this->findDemanded($demand);** will return an array with all the news matching the demand-array but the results is empty.

If i use **$this->findDemandedRaw($demand);** it returns the correct plain query (tested in phpmyadmin and returns the correct values).

I'm pretty new on TYPO3 and i don't know how it works really well, some one has any hints about that?

The news extension key is: **news**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

The returned value was an object not an array, so now i'm able to iterate every item inside the object and return it as a json.

My bad, sorry :)